# Cómo obtener las keys y values de un objeto y generar una tabla

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Soy novata con springboot. Estoy usando una bbdd en postgressql con postgis.

En el código que muestro lo que hago es leer el inputStream de un fichero geojson y procesarlo.

Antes guardaba las propiedades del fichero geojson, que es un objeto con campos, como jsonb. Pero ahora quiero obtener cada una de las keys del objeto de las propiedades y su tipo para crear la tabla dinámicamente e insertar la información.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
public class ParseGeojsonStream {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParseGeojsonStream.class);

    private static Gson gson;

    private static List<String> listKeys;
    private static List<String> listTypes;

    @Bean
    public static ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return mapper;
    }

    public static void parseJson(final String name, final TableGeoJsonStream tableStream, final InputStream is) throws IOException {

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.serializeNulls();
        gson = builder.create();

        // Create and configure an ObjectMapper instance
        ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        // Create a JsonParser instance
        try (JsonParser jsonParser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(is)) {

            // Check the first token
            if (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Expected content to be an object");
            }

            JsonParser featureJson = findFeaturesToken(jsonParser);

            if (featureJson == null) {
                throw new IOException("Expected content to be not null");
            }

            if (featureJson.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
                throw new IOException("Expected content to be an array");
            }

            List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();

            boolean firstFeature = true;
            // Iterate over the tokens until the end of the array
            while (featureJson.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                // Read a contact instance using ObjectMapper and do something with it
                // De 50 en 50
                Feature feature = mapper.readValue(featureJson, Feature.class);
                features.add(feature);

                if (firstFeature) {
                    firstFeature = false;
                    // create table
                    getKeyAndTypeOfProperties((Map<String, ?>) feature.getProperties());
                    createTableWithFields(tableStream, name);
                }


                if (features.size() == 50) {
                    generateSQLValues(tableStream, features);
                    features.clear();
                }
            }

            // Añadimos el resto que sobra
            if (features.size() > 0) {
                generateSQLValues(tableStream, features);
                features.clear();
            }

        }
    }

    private static void getKeyAndTypeOfProperties(Map<String, ?> objectproperties) {
        listKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
        listTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

        Iterator<String> it = objectproperties.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) it.next();
            log.info("KEY: "+ key);
            listKeys.add(key);
            listTypes.add(getTypeOfKey(key, objectproperties.get(key)));
        }
    }

    private static String getTypeOfKey(String key, Object value) {
        String type = "";
        if (value == null) {
            if (key.toLowerCase().contains("id")) {
                type = "int8";
            } else if (key.toLowerCase().contains("fecha") || key.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
                type = "date";
            } else {
                type = "text";              
            }
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            type = "text";
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            type = "boolean";
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            type = "decimal";
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            type = "int8";
        } else if (value instanceof Date) {
            type = "date";
        } else {
            type = "text";
        }
        return type;
    }

    private static JsonParser findFeaturesToken(JsonParser jsonParser) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
        JsonParser json = jsonParser;
        try {
            while(true) {
                String text = json.getText().toLowerCase();
                if ( text.equalsIgnoreCase(GEOJSONConstants.ApiJSON.FEATURES.toLowerCase()) ) {
                    return json;
                }
                json.nextToken();               
            }           
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void createTableWithFields(final TableGeoJsonStream tableStream, final String name) {
        String keys = "";
        for (int i=0; i<listKeys.size(); i++) {
            keys += listKeys.get(i) + " " + listTypes.get(i) + ", ";
        }
        keys = keys + "geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326), primary key (table_id)";
        tableStream.createTableWithColumnsDinamically(name, keys);
    }

    private static void generateSQLValues(final TableGeoJsonStream tableStream, final List<Feature> features) {
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableStream.getCheckedNameTable(); 
//      String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + checkedNameTable + " ( properties, geom ) VALUES ( '" + property + "', ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + geometry + "'), 4326) ));"; 
        String keys = "";
        for (int i=0; i<listKeys.size(); i++) {
            keys += listKeys.get(i) + ", ";
        }
        SQL += " ( " + keys + " geom ) VALUES ";

        String allValues = "";
        for (int i=0; i<features.size(); i++) {
            String values = " ( ";
            Feature feature = features.get(i);
            Map<String, ?> properties = (Map<String, ?>) feature.getProperties();
            for (int j=0; j<listKeys.size(); j++) {
                values += properties.get(listKeys.get(j)) + ", ";           
            }
            // añadir campo geometria
            values += feature.getGeometry() + " ";
            values = (i == features.size()) ? values + " ) " : values + " ), ";             
            allValues += values;
        }   
        log.info("All Values: " + allValues);




//      String SQL_BEGIN = "INSERT INTO " + tableStream.getCheckedNameTable() + " ( keys de las propiedades, geom ) VALUES ";
//      String SQL = SQL_BEGIN + SQL_VALUES;
//      tableStream.insertMultipleRows(SQL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido resolverlo, gracias por vuestra ayuda y apoyo.
Espero que le pueda servir a alguien y si alguien puede optimizar el código estaría agradecido.

Saludos

public class ParseGeojsonStream {

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParseGeojsonStream.class);

private static Gson gson;

private static List<String> listKeys;
private static List<String> listTypes;

private static String VALUES;
private static int position;

@Bean
public static ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    return mapper;
}

public static void parseJson(final String name, final TableGeoJsonStream tableStream, final InputStream is) throws IOException {

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.serializeNulls();
    gson = builder.create();

    // Create and configure an ObjectMapper instance
    ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    // Create a JsonParser instance
    try (JsonParser jsonParser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(is)) {

        // Check the first token
        if (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected content to be an object");
        }

        JsonParser featureJson = findFeaturesToken(jsonParser);

        if (featureJson == null) {
            throw new IOException("Expected content to be not null");
        }

        if (featureJson.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            throw new IOException("Expected content to be an array");
        }

        List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();

        boolean firstFeature = true;
        // Iterate over the tokens until the end of the array
        while (featureJson.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            // Read a contact instance using ObjectMapper and do something with it
            // De 50 en 50
            Feature feature = mapper.readValue(featureJson, Feature.class);
            features.add(feature);

            if (firstFeature) {
                firstFeature = false;
                // create table
                getKeyAndTypeOfProperties((Map<String, ?>) feature.getProperties());
                createTableWithFields(tableStream, name);
            }


            if (features.size() == 50) {
                generateSQLValues(tableStream, features);
                features.clear();
            }
        }

        // Añadimos el resto que sobra
        if (features.size() > 0) {
            generateSQLValues(tableStream, features);
            features.clear();
        }

    }
}

private static void getKeyAndTypeOfProperties(Map<String, ?> objectproperties) {
    listKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    listTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<String> it = objectproperties.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key = (String) it.next();
        listKeys.add(key);
        listTypes.add(getTypeOfKey(key, objectproperties.get(key)));
    }
}

private static String getTypeOfKey(String key, Object value) {
    String type = "";
    if (value == null) {
        if (key.toLowerCase().contains("id")) {
            type = "int8";
        } else if (key.toLowerCase().contains("fecha") || key.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
            type = "date";
        } else {
            type = "text";              
        }
    } else if (value instanceof String) {
        type = "text";
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        type = "boolean";
    } else if (value instanceof Double) {
        type = "decimal";
    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        type = "int8";
    } else if (value instanceof Date) {
        type = "date";
    } else {
        type = "text";
    }
    return type;
}

private static JsonParser findFeaturesToken(JsonParser jsonParser) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    JsonParser json = jsonParser;
    try {
        while(true) {
            String text = json.getText().toLowerCase();
            if ( text.equalsIgnoreCase(GEOJSONConstants.ApiJSON.FEATURES.toLowerCase()) ) {
                return json;
            }
            json.nextToken();               
        }           
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private static void createTableWithFields(final TableGeoJsonStream tableStream, final String name) {
    String keys = "";
    for (int i=0; i<listKeys.size(); i++) {
        keys += listKeys.get(i) + " " + listTypes.get(i) + ", ";
    }
    tableStream.createTableWithColumnsDinamically(name, keys);
}

private static String createSQLValuesScheme() {
    String valuesScheme = "";
    String keys = "";
    for (int i=0; i<listKeys.size(); i++) {
        keys += listKeys.get(i) + ", ";
    }
    valuesScheme += " ( " + keys + "geom ) VALUES ";
    return valuesScheme;
}

private static String getAllPropertiesFromGson(JsonElement jsonElement) {
    VALUES = "";
    JsonObject jsonProperties = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

    int totalValues = jsonProperties.size()-1;
    position = 0;
    jsonProperties.keySet().forEach( keyStr -> {
        Object keyValue = jsonProperties.get(keyStr);
        VALUES = (position == totalValues) ? VALUES + "'" + keyValue.toString().replace("\"", "") + "'" : VALUES + "'" + keyValue.toString().replace("\"", "") + "', ";
        position++;
    });
    return VALUES;
}

private static void generateSQLValues(final TableGeoJsonStream tableStream, final List<Feature> features) {
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableStream.getCheckedNameTable(); 
    String SCHEME_VALUES = createSQLValuesScheme();

    String VALUES = "";
    for (int i=0; i<features.size(); i++) {
        if (features.size() - 1 == i) {
            VALUES += "(" + getAllPropertiesFromGson( gson.toJsonTree(features.get(i).getProperties()) ) + ", ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + gson.toJson(features.get(i).getGeometry()) + "'), 4326)));";
        } else {
            VALUES += "(" + getAllPropertiesFromGson( gson.toJsonTree(features.get(i).getProperties()) ) + ", ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + gson.toJson(features.get(i).getGeometry()) + "'), 4326))), ";

        }
    }
    String SQL_COMPLETE = SQL + SCHEME_VALUES + VALUES;
    tableStream.insertMultipleRows(SQL_COMPLETE);
}
```

}